# For large files, DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA fails on Autonomous DB with ORA-30094: failed to find the time zone data file for version 39 in $ORACLE_HOME/

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

When I execute the following in order to load data to my Oracle Cloud Autonomous DB from Oracle Cloud bucket object (a CSV file):

```
DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA(
    table_name =>'test_landing_zone',
    credential_name =>'test2',
    file_uri_list => 'https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/idqt8fo79xkv/b/test-upload/o/2025.csv',
    format => json_object('type' value 'csv', 'ignoremissingcolumns' value 'true', 'trimspaces' value 'lrtrim', 'ignoreblanklines' value 'true', 'delimiter' value ';')
);
```

for a small file (100s of rows), all goes well. Once I try with 1000s of rows, I get:

```
ORA-20000: ORA-30094: failed to find the time zone data file for version 39 in $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo
ORA-30094: failed to find the time zone data file for version 39 in $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 1563
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 7896
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 7919
ORA-06512: at line 2
Error at Line: 7 Column: 0
```

The larger file is literally the content of the smaller one, copied many times (to prevent this issue being caused by something in data).

Googling recommended to patch some libraries, but as this is DBaaS (Oracle Cloud Autonomous DB), that is out of the picture.

I will be grateful for any help. Thank you!

Comment: Definitely raise a support ticket for that, because that should not be happening

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - I have raised one, but Oracle technical support is the worst I have ever seen. So far they provided just a few obviously unhelpful suggestions - e.g. check some time zone file on the DB server’s filesystem (makes no sense, I am using DBaaS, with no access to the filesystem), and so on…

Comment: Got an SR# ? I can chase this up internally

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - thank you, really appreciate it. It is SR #3-33558850881.

Comment: will chase up and see what I can find out, but comms will (and should) be still via the SR

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - sorry to say, but the Oracle technical help continues being totally pathetic... As you can see from the Service Request. And that is after two weeks.